# "He never do the things breach the benefits of group." Why "do" instead of "did/does"?

Tags: tense, verbs

I read an article , there was a sentence in it :

> He never do the things breach the benefits of group.

My question is why it used "do" in the sentence? I thought it should be "did" or "does"..

Comment: That sentence is grammatically incorrect, so it's impossible to say why it is the way it is.  Where did you find it?

Comment: Hi stangdon.,  thank you for answering . Actually it was an example sentence in a dictionary APP. So how about I change the sentence to this : He never did something to hurt his friend . (  If in this sentence , the verb "did "is correct? can I change it into "does "?)

Comment: This is a horrid sentence. There's nothing right about it. In your comment, "something" is wrong. "He never did/does anything to hurt his friend" but they mean different things.

Comment: If you found that sentence in an app, you should throw away that app immediately and warn other people not to use it, because that sentence is horribly mangled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example sentence

> He never *do* the things breach the benefits of group.

is grammatically incorrect and possibly should be

> He never *will* do the things *to* breach the benefits of group.
>   He never *did* the things *to* breach the benefits of group.
>   He never *does* the things *to* breach the benefits of group.

In your second sentence (in the comments)

> He never *does* something to hurt his friend.
>   He never *did* something to hurt his friend.

Both sentences are correct, it is only a change in tense, the first being *present continuous tense* and the second being *past tense*.

Comment: "Something" just sounds wrong. "Anything" is much more idiomatic there.

Comment: But it is perfectly correct.

Comment: Thank you all for helping !! especially thank for Peter's example sentence , they are very clear and do solve my question

Comment: Hi , Peter ,sorry , I am new here , so don't really know how to accept the answer, I chose the up triangle sign on the left , did it mean I already accept it? If not , please tell me how to do it, thank you